# Using Google's Python-ADB over a local network

Tags: android, python, adb

Pretty self explanatory, as the title says, is there a way to connect to an `ADB over TCP` enabled device on a network, using Google's [Python-ADB](https://github.com/google/python-adb/) library?

I saw something mentioned in the [adb_commands.py](https://github.com/google/python-adb/blob/master/adb/adb_commands.py) file to do with a TCP connection, here is the comment:

```
If serial specifies a TCP address:port,
then a TCP connection is used instead of a USB connection.
```

However there is no examples of doing this.

I have the devices IP address and port, as well as the correct ADB keys, and I was wondering if someone could supply an example code snippet.

Thanks heaps :)

P.S. I am using `python3.7`, and here is the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux Kali 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2kali1 (2018-10-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply pass `ip:port` to the `serial` positional argument:

```
import os.path as op

from adb import adb_commands
from adb import sign_m2crypto

# KitKat+ devices require authentication
signer = sign_m2crypto.M2CryptoSigner(
    op.expanduser('~/.android/adbkey'))
# Connect to the device
device = adb_commands.AdbCommands()
device.ConnectDevice(port_path=None, serial="192.168.0.140:5555",
    rsa_keys=[signer])

# Now we can use Shell, Pull, Push, etc!
# for i in range(10):
#     print device.Shell('echo %d' % i)

print device.Shell('uname -a').rstrip()
print "%s, %s" % (device.Shell('getprop ro.product.brand').rstrip(),
                  device.Shell('getprop ro.product.model').rstrip())
print device.Shell('getprop ro.build.version.release').rstrip()
print device.List('/system')
```

Output on my device:

```
Linux localhost 4.4.78-perf-g27c78a6 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 6 03:28:28 CST 2018 aarch64
Xiaomi, MI 6
8.0.0
[DeviceFile(filename=bytearray(b'.'), mode=16877,
...
```

Tested with Python 2.7.15; the library isn't fully py3 ready yet.
Note that you still have to make your device listen in `tcpip` mode first by doing `adb tcpip 5555` or another port.